# Application crash while scrollup and scrolldown

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, swiperefreshlayout

I am using `swiperefreshlayout` to refresh the list view.  While refreshing, when I try to scroll up or scroll down the list view,  the app is crashing. Can someone give me the solution to my problem.

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at latestcardview.CustomBaseAdapter.getView(CustomBaseAdapter.java:206)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2467)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:662)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5424)
at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3569)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:3950)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3788)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8444)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2436)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2178)at    com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2386)
at  com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2764)
 at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2335)
 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8655)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4094)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
   at  android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3773)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3694)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3660)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3668)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3640)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5940)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5872)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6030)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:211)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method )
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:197)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6001)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6062)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:792)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:596)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:555)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:778)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:102     9)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

**Code**

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private int ConvertPixelsToDp(float pixelValue)
{
    int dp = (int) ((pixelValue)/ Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    return dp;
}

private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
ArrayList<String> userName,
        jokeLike, jok_id,jok_desc,jok_img,jok_is_active,jok_nsfw,jok_total_comments,jok_total_flags,
        jok_total_shares,jok_created_on,jok_modified_on, jok_userimg,likeCount,dislikeCount,popularJoke,languagename;
TextView tv_share,tv_comment,tv_smile,tv_frown;
Bitmap bmp;
String image_url,path;
Context context;
String joke_status;
String joke_id, status, user_id, time_pass,user_type_id,desc;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences pref;
int width;
String time,userLikeString, userDislikeString,popularstatus;
String big_url;
String jokeingid;
String option;
String like_response;


public CustomBaseAdapter(FragmentActivity mainActivity,
                         ArrayList<String> UserName,
                         ArrayList<String> JokeLike,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_id,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_desc,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_img,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_is_active,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_nsfw,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_total_comments,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_total_flags,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_total_shares,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_created_on,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_modified_on,
                         ArrayList<String> Jok_userimg,
                         ArrayList<String> LikeCount,
                         ArrayList<String> DislikeCount,
                         ArrayList<String> JokePopular,
                         ArrayList<String>languageName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    /*
    set parameter to the variable
     */
    userName            = UserName;
    jokeLike            = JokeLike;
    jok_id              = Jok_id;
    jok_desc            = Jok_desc;
    jok_img             = Jok_img;
    jok_is_active       = Jok_is_active;
    jok_nsfw            = Jok_nsfw;
    jok_total_comments  = Jok_total_comments;
    jok_total_flags     = Jok_total_flags;
    jok_total_shares    = Jok_total_shares;
    jok_created_on      = Jok_created_on;
    jok_modified_on     = Jok_modified_on;
    jok_userimg         = Jok_userimg;
    likeCount           = LikeCount;
    dislikeCount        = DislikeCount;
    popularJoke         = JokePopular;
    languagename        = languageName;
    context             = mainActivity;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return userName.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder = new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_backend_latest, null);

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();

    user_id = pref.getString("userId", null); // getting String
    user_type_id = pref.getString("typeId", null);

    holder.UserNameTxt   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_username); // set textView to xml id
    holder.up            = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.up);
    holder.down          = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.down);
    holder.user_profile  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_user_profile);
    holder.jokeId        = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokesId);
    holder.username      = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_username);
    holder.description   = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_description);
    holder.smiles        = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_smiles);
    holder.frowns        = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_frowns);
    holder.comments      = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_comments);
    holder.share         = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_share);
    holder.time          = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.time);
    holder.languagename  = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.lang);
    holder.list_image    = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.jokes_list_image);
    holder.extend        = (LinearLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.extend);
    holder.share_icon    = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.share_icon);
    holder.flag_icon     = (LinearLayout)rowView.findViewById(R.id.flag_icon);
    holder.comment_icon  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.comment_icon);
    holder.markPopular   = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mark_popular);

    tv_share = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_share);
    tv_comment = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_comments);
    tv_smile = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smiles);
    tv_frown = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_frowns);

    if(user_type_id.equals("1")){
        holder.markPopular.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    holder.UserNameTxt.setText(userName.get(position).toString());// set the value to textView
    holder.smiles.setText(likeCount.get(position).toString());
    holder.frowns.setText(dislikeCount.get(position).toString());
    holder.comments.setText(jok_total_comments.get(position));
    holder.share.setText(jok_total_shares.get(position));
    holder.description.setText(jok_desc.get(position).toString());

    if(languagename.get(position).toString().equals("")) {
        holder.languagename.setText("Not Mentioned");
    } else {

        holder.languagename.setText(languagename.get(position).toString());
    }


    Log.e("Languagename",languagename.get(position).toString());

    time = jok_created_on.get(position).toString().substring(0, 19);
    String userjokeposttime = jok_created_on.get(position).toString();
    Log.e("userjokeposttime", userjokeposttime);
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    DateTime jodatime = dtf.parseDateTime(time);
    DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(dtfOut.print(jodatime));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss");



    width = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    DisplayMetrics display = this.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(display.widthPixels);


    return rowView;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView UserNameTxt, jokeId, username, description, smiles, frowns, comments, share, time,languagename;  //Initialize TextView variable
    ImageView up, down, user_profile, list_image, comment_icon;
    LinearLayout extend,share_icon,flag_icon;
    CheckBox markPopular;

}

public class LikeTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Global_Url.like_url);

        try {

            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jid",joke_id));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", user_id));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", status));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            Log.e("jokegdg",joke_id+user_id+status);


            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
            String jarray = jsono.getString("status");


            if(jarray.equals("0")){

                Toast.makeText(context, "you didnt like", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, like_response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.e("Response", result.toString());


    }

}

    }



    protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(), bmp, "Title", null);

        Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, desc);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        sendIntent.setType("image/*");
        context.startActivity(sendIntent);

    }
}
       }
      }
    }

    public class Latest_Jokes extends Fragment {

View inflatedView = null;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ArrayList<GetSetJokes> jokesList = new ArrayList<GetSetJokes>();
ArrayList<String> userName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jokeLike = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_id = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_desc = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_img = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_is_active = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_nsfw = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_total_comments = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_total_flags = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_total_shares = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_created_on = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_modified_on = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_username = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> jok_userimg = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> like_status = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> likeCount = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> dislikeCount = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> popularJoke = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> languagename = new ArrayList<String>();
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = null;
private Context mContext;
int width;
String nsfwcode, jsonStr, userId;
JSONArray jarray;
ListView listview;

ImageView extend;
private String new_url = Global_Url.jokes_url;
int current_page = 1;

String con_url = new_url.concat("?page" + String.valueOf(2));
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences pref;


private int SCROLL_TO_POSITION = 0;
private int mPreLast;

int iTest = 0;

public Latest_Jokes() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_jokes, container, false);



    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.yelow);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {


                    SCROLL_TO_POSITION = 0;
                    iTest = 0;
                    current_page = 1;
                    int mPreLast;

                    jok_id.clear();
                    jok_desc.clear();
                    jok_img.clear();
                    jok_is_active.clear();
                    jok_nsfw.clear();
                    jok_total_comments.clear();
                    jok_total_flags.clear();
                    jok_total_shares.clear();
                    jok_created_on.clear();
                    jok_modified_on.clear();
                    userName.clear();
                    jokeLike.clear();
                    jok_userimg.clear();
                    likeCount.clear();
                    dislikeCount.clear();
                    popularJoke.clear();
                    languagename.clear();
                    new LatestTask().execute();
                }
            });






    pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();


    width = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    extend = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.extend);
    listview = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list_jokes);
    userId = pref.getString("userId", null);
    nsfwcode = pref.getString("nswKey",null);// getting String
        new LatestTask().execute(nsfwcode,userId);


    listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {


            int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if (lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                if (mPreLast != lastItem) {
                    mPreLast = lastItem;

                    if (SCROLL_TO_POSITION >= 10) {
                        new LatestTask().execute();
                        iTest = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    });


    return inflatedView;

}


private class LatestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Global_Url.jokes_url);

        try {

            userId = pref.getString("userId", null);
            nsfwcode = pref.getString("nswKey",null);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", String.valueOf(current_page)));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", userId));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nsfw", nsfwcode));
            Log.e("userId",userId+nsfwcode);


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        jsonStr = result;
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            JSONObject jsono = null;
            try {
                jsono = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    jok_id.add(object.getString("jok_id"));
                    jok_desc.add(object.getString("jok_desc"));
                    jok_img.add(object.getString("jok_img"));
                    jok_is_active.add(object.getString("jok_is_active"));
                    jok_nsfw.add(object.getString("jok_nsfw"));
                    jok_total_comments.add(object.getString("jok_total_comments"));
                    jok_total_flags.add(object.getString("jok_total_flags"));
                    jok_total_shares.add(object.getString("jok_total_shares"));
                    jok_created_on.add(object.getString("jok_created_on"));
                    jok_modified_on.add(object.getString("jok_modified_on"));
                    userName.add(object.getString("jok_username"));
                    jokeLike.add(object.getString("likeStatus"));
                    jok_userimg.add(object.getString("jok_userimg"));
                    likeCount.add(object.getString("likeCount"));
                    dislikeCount.add(object.getString("dislikeCount"));
                    popularJoke.add(object.getString("jok_is_popular"));
                    languagename.add(object.getString("language"));


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), userName, jokeLike, jok_id, jok_desc, jok_img, jok_is_active, jok_nsfw,
                jok_total_comments, jok_total_flags, jok_total_shares, jok_created_on
                , jok_modified_on, jok_userimg, likeCount, dislikeCount, popularJoke,languagename));



        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }


        if (iTest == 1) {
            listview.setSelection(SCROLL_TO_POSITION-2);
        }

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                SCROLL_TO_POSITION = current_page * 10;
                current_page++;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is error?, put your logcat traces

Comment: Without crash log it's quite difficult to help since I don't have a real-time debugger attached to my brain but as a suggestion (and unrelated to your question), I suggest getting rid of the millions of lists you've created and instead use a single list of a container style class that has all the values you want. Should make debugging this easier as well.

Comment: i updated my code and logcat please tel me the solutions

Comment: Its IndexOutOfBoundsException after refreshing may be your listview not getting data for all row check your array size and listview item count.both should match.

Comment: thanks got it!!!@KundanKumarRoy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I also separated the log and code blocks and titled them by enclosing the titles with two asterisks.